# Diffusional equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am still new to Mathematica.

I'm trying to solve a diffusional equation

```
DSolveValue[
  {D[y[x], {x, 2}] - 0*D[y[x], x] + y[x] == 0, 
   {y'[0] == 0, y[99999999999] == 0}}, 
  y[x], x]
```

but it returns 0. But I know that there is an answer different from 0.

---

So when I don't use `y'[0] == 0` in the boundary conditions I see a normal solving. What am I doing wrong?

Can u teach me how to use constants instead of `0*D[y[x], x]` -- something like `k^2*D[y[x], x]`?

Comment: Are you sure there is a non-zero solution *with these boundary conditions*?  Note that this isn't really a diffusion equation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: @m_goldberg do you have a script for this particular standard comment of yours?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Yes, and for several others as well.

Comment: @m_goldberg is there a relevant meta thread at hand?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. Not that I know of. Certainly not one written by me.

Comment: @m_goldberg `*sigh*`. I was hoping this was a publicly available tool. The standard *"Welcome, I hope you become a regular contributor..."* etc, I understand, are also personal scripts of individual users then?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. I do use a publicly available tool. It is called BBEdit and is commercially available for OS X. But since it is not a tool I created, I can't make it available to others.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP. If you are still interested in getting a list of my frequently posted reasons for closing, ask a question on that topic in meta and I will post a list of them there.

Comment: @m_goldberg Here is the [meta thread](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1896/26956), although you may have misinterpreted my intent.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're asking for $y''(x)+y(x)==0$
The function $y=0$  fits this equation. Mathematica is giving you exactly what you're asking for.
If you want to add a constant, just add a constant.

```
DSolveValue[{k y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[99999999999] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

Gives as its solution

```
C[1] Cos[x/Sqrt[k]] - C[1] Cot[99999999999/Sqrt[k]] Sin[x/Sqrt[k]]
```

If this is not what you're looking for, you need to double check your equations, for as @Szabolcs said, this does not appear to be the one dimensional diffusion equation.

Comment: Hmmm...I pasted and get 0 again(((

Comment: @Eugene He probably meant `y[99999999999] == c`

Comment: @Eugene Be sure to quit kernel. I'm not sure what you want exactly, but the as I stated, you can add any constant wherever you want. Replace any with 0 you want from `DSolveValue[{c1 y''[x] + y[x] == c2, y'[0] == 0, 
  y[99999999999] == c3}, y[x], x]`